# compare a variable to normal limit quantile

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data
Two exposures, each exposure has a normal upper limit.

| ID | exposure1 | exposure2 | limit1 | limit 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 300 | 250 | 300 |
| 2 | 160 | 600 | 250 | 300 |
| 3 | 160 | 700 | 250 | 300 |
| 4 | 450 | 200 | 250 | 300 |
| 5 | 100 | 50 | 250 | 300 |
| 6 | 200 | 90 | 250 | 300 |

Question:

1. How can I present a visual plot of how many people and (%) with an exposure level compared to the corresponding normal limit for each exposure? Present in quantile fashion like below 10%, below 25%, 50%, 75%, 90%, and above the limit 100%.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `qqfun` function from `gap` package?

Comment: I am not familiar with this code, can you please demonstrate how to use it?

Comment: It gives a quantile-comparison plot. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to build a graph with exposure listed
It gives the number of people with an exposure in each quantile according to the limit for the exposure
For example
exposure 1: 
10 (5%) below 10% of the limit
15 (7%) below 25% of the limit
.... and finally number of people with exposure above the limit